# Could have, Should have, Would have, Must have, Might have - Time Adverbs

Tags: grammar, adverbs

When talking about past ability or possibility, we use **could have** or **might have**.

When talking about past obligation or suggestion, we use **should have**.

When talking about past strong guess, we use **must have**.

When talking about past intention, we use **would have**.

I know the topic above has been discussed thousands of times in this forum, but nobody has ever asked if they have any limitation when it comes to time adverbs. So, I decided to ask the below question. By the way, I guess that since they are used to describe and portray things in the past, their time adverbs are just like simple tense's.

Question:

Can they (would have, could have, might have, should have, must have) be used with past time adverbs: yesterday, last year, last week, by May 5, at 5 pm, by 10 am.....etc?

Example provided to make discussion easier:

> > 1. He **could have** played with his friends online at 5 yesterday. (which I am not sure about, so I take a guess)

> > 2. He **should have** studied smart and hard last year. Courses last year were important for his future career. (I don't know if he studied hard and smart last year. I just want to convey the idea "he was supposed to study hard and smart")

> > 3. Students **must have** gone to class instead of taking class online in the 90s.

> > 4. The patient **must have** taken the medication at 5 last night. That medication is important part of the treatment. (the patient had to take that medication at 5 last night.)

> > 5. In high school, with the internet, I **would have** got a better result on the admission test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use these sorts of phrases with time adverbs just fine.

However "must have", in this case, basically describes a strong guess or belief.  It does not mean there was a requirement or need.

> ...*must have taken* the medication...

basically means:

> ...*almost definitely took* the medication...

It doesn't mean:

> ...*needed to take* the medication...

or:

> ...*was required to take* the medication...

Comment: Can we use their negative forms (couldn't have, wouldn't have...etc) with those time adverbs?

Comment: @vincentlin Sure, negatives are fine.